# Adding a white box for content over a background image

Tags: html, css

**What I want it to look like**

[image]

I have uploaded a photo of exactly what I'm trying to do. Just to clarify, this is an assignment and I do not want it to be done for me. I'm simply asking how I should go about doing this. The white box that has text boxes within it is what I am trying to create. Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 4):

Just add all the elements of the box inside a `div` tag and then you can manipulate the `divs` `background-color` `positioning` etc. using `CSS`.

```css
.white-box {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    <!--other positioning attributes-->
}
```

```html
<div class="white-box">
    Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a form! If its not a form and you are trying to do it via css, you are going to do what frogger said.

Here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp